# How can I resolve /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found in my CGAL cmake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, cgal

I built a CGAL project (with CMAKE) on Ubuntu, but when I run "make" in an example project (cpp project), I get the error:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As far as I know, Ubuntu uses `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, not `/usr/lib64`...

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your gcc:

> yum update gcc

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11738170)

Comment: @HappyCoder: This is **an answer** - it suggests decision for the problem. Some problems occured while programming can be resolved with non-programming means. If you think the answer is not useful, you are free to downvote it.

Comment: Well, it ended in the "Low quality Post" queue. Maybe the author can elaborate more, and then it is good to go :)

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks~ :)

Comment: @HappyCoder: `Maybe the author can elaborate more, and then it is good to go` - Yes, I agree with that. (@an unique monkey: This is hint for your:)). In the most cases, LQP queue means .. low quality. But "low quality" doesn't mean that post should be *deleted*, sometimes *downvote* is more appropriate action.